# Add library jar files in Java Task?

Tags: java, ant, jar

The `spark-de.jar` used other jar files as libraries. Assume running `spark-de.jar` requires `lib1.jar` and `lib2.jar`, how to set them in the following `Java` task of `Ant`?

```
<target name="makeQuery">
    <java classname="sparkDemo.SparkTest" failonerror="true">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/spark-de.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<target name="makeQuery">
    <java classname="sparkDemo.SparkTest" failonerror="true">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/spark-de.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib1.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib2.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```